# boost::mpl::map fails boost::mpl::equal?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mpl

Boost MPL documentation  states that boost::map::equal

"Returns a true-valued Integral Constant if the two sequences Seq1 and Seq2 
are identical  when *compared* _element_ *by* _element_ .

but it seems that the associative sequence map is not checked for equality **element** _*wise*_:

The following demo will show this: Map2 should equal Map3, which both  increment the 'int_<1>' value_type at 'key'. Look at the typedef defining Map3.
Size and the only element is dumped n the demo:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/mpl/map.hpp>
#include<boost/mpl/at.hpp>
#include<boost/mpl/insert.hpp>
#include<boost/mpl/erase_key.hpp>
#include<boost/mpl/pair.hpp>
#include<boost/mpl/int.hpp>
#include<boost/mpl/plus.hpp>
#include<boost/mpl/equal.hpp>
#include<boost/mpl/size.hpp>
#include<boost/mpl/front.hpp>

namespace mpl = boost::mpl;
using mpl::int_;

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::is_same;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    typedef int key;

    typedef typename mpl::map<mpl::pair<key, int_<1>>> Map;
    typedef typename mpl::map<mpl::pair<key, int_<2>>> Map2;

    typedef typename mpl::insert<
    typename mpl::erase_key<Map,
                            key>::type, 
        mpl::pair<key, 
                  typename mpl::plus<int_<1>, 
                                     typename mpl::at<Map, key>::type>::type
        >::type
    >::type Map3;

    cout << "equal? " << mpl::equal<Map2,Map3>::type::value << endl;
    cout << "size? " << mpl::size<Map3>::value << endl;
    cout << "key type at front? " << typeid(mpl::front<Map3>::type::first).name() << endl;
    cout << "value type at front? " << mpl::front<Map3>::type::second::value << endl;

    cout << "expected size? " << mpl::size<Map2>::value << endl;
    cout << "expected key type at front? " << typeid(mpl::front<Map2>::type::first).name() << endl;
    cout << "expected value type at front? " << mpl::front<Map2>::type::second::value << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I am using gcc 4.8.1 with boost 1.51

Comment: Also the [tag:mpl] tag is not related to Boost.MPL. The tag you want is [tag:boost-mpl]. You'll probably get an answer by someone who knows what he/she's talking about if you add it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it does not work as expected is that `mpl::plus<int_<1>, mpl::at<Map, key>::type` is `mpl::integral_constant<int, 2>`, whereas `mpl::int_<2>` is a different type.

A working version:

```
typedef mpl::map<mpl::pair<key, mpl::integral_c<int, 1>>> Map;
typedef mpl::map<mpl::pair<key, mpl::integral_c<int, 2>>> Map2;

typedef mpl::insert<
    mpl::erase_key<Map, key>::type,
    mpl::pair<key, mpl::plus<mpl::integral_c<int, 1>, mpl::at<Map, key>::type>::type>
>::type Map3;
```

Comment: You answered another problem, which is only incidental to his problem (that plus returns a different type than passed).

Comment: @GrapschKnutsch I think you right that the order of elements in a `mpl::map` is unspecified and `mpl::equal` only works here because both maps each have only one element. On the other hand, `mpl::equal` does not specify any specific order of comparisons, so it could be partially specialized for `mpl::map` to do the right thing. I did not verify that though.

Answer (score 2):

The result of inserting elements in a different order into a boost::mpl::map are different types -- even if the mapping is the same.
To work around this problem, you could rebuild the sequence by sorting it every time you modify it. This adds strongly to the complexity the compiler has to deal with,
especially if the number of entries are larger.